# What does this mean: NSString *string = NO ? @"aaa" : @"bbb";

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa

I was reading over the Dropbox API and I found this line:

```
NSString* title = [[DBSession sharedSession] isLinked] ? @"Unlink Dropbox" : @"Link Dropbox";
```

I've never seen that syntax before? What is it called and what does it mean? I can tell what it does just from looking at it but could someone tell me about it?

Comment: sorry, i now realize this is probably a duplicate.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That is a so-called [ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation)

Ternary operators in C have the following pattern `condition ? true-expression : false-expression`.

If `condition` evaluates to `YES`, then `true-expression` gets evaluated, otherwise `false-expression`.

In your particular case `title` would get assigned to `@"Unlink Dropbox"` if `[[DBSession sharedSession] isLinked]` returns `YES`, otherwise `@"Link Dropbox"`.

Comment: And is very nice to use instead of if when you only want to make an assignment with only 2 outcomes.

Comment: They also come in handy when having to work-around the lack of `[NSArray firstObject]` à la `([array count] ? [array objectAtIndex:0] : nil)`.

Comment: There is not need for a walkaround If you use `[array lastObject]` you will receive `nil` if the array is empty.

Comment: Absolutely right. I wasn't talking about `lastObject` though, but about `firstObject`. Only for arrays of count `0-1` `firstObject` and `lastObject` are equivalent. For everything else: workaround. Sucks, but that's the reality.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use this to print `BOOL`s values like:

```
NSLog(@"%@", boolVal ? @"YES" : @"NO");
```

Answer (score 0):

That is the [Ternary Operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation).